# C++11 std ref to ECMAScript (Javascript) spec?

Tags: javascript, c++, c++11

In the C++11 standard document it says:

> The following referenced documents are indispensable for the application of this document:
>
> - Ecma International, ECMAScript Language Specification, Standard Ecma-262, third edition, 1999.

What exactly is the dependency of the C++11 spec on the Javascript spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section "28.13 Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar" depends on ECMA-262:

> #### 28.13 Modified ECMAScript regular expression grammar `[re.grammar]`
>
> 1 The regular expression grammar recognized by basic_regex objects constructed with the ECMAScript flag is that specified by ECMA-262, except as specified below.

The regular expression grammar is specified in section [15.10 RegExp (Regular Expression) Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10) and [A.7 Regular Expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.7) in ECMA-262.

Comment: Anywhere we can learn what the exceptions are («except as specified below»)?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: C++11 standard, section 28.13, as written above. Drafts which are almost the same as the standard can be found at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/. I quoted N3337, which was the first draft after the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 4):

`regex` offers an ECMAScript-compatible regex syntax, by default or enabled by the appropriate flag:

```
#include <regex>

std::regex r{"...", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript};
```

ECMAScript is the default; other syntaxes include `basic`, `extended`, `awk`, `grep` and `egrep` (all as specified by the appropriate sections of POSIX).